# Why does jQuery animation only runs once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to get my animation to complete only once without reloading the page.

There is a similar question about the same issue, but I can not seem to get it to re-fire on mouseenter. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#root').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      'right': '200'
    });
  });
  $('#root').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      'left': '200'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#root {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Because the value of right and left needs to be removed from the element after the cycle is completed. This can be achieved easily with css transitions

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to make it slide or grow?

Answer (score 3):

You're animating two different properties, `right` and `left`. Those are aren't the direction they're travelling, they represent how far offset from the left and right sides of their parent container they are.

The way you have it now, you're applying those two properties and never removing them. If you're trying to make the element slide out of the way like a drawer, you should only be animating the `left` property, adding `200px` to it on `mouseenter` and setting `left` back to `0px` on `mouseleave`. If you're trying to make the element appear to grow, you should animate `width` or `right` instead, but follow the same resetting procedure on `mouseleave`.

**HOWEVER!** an easier way to achieve what you want it to just do it with pure CSS transitions. These will animate more smoothly, are often GPU accelerated, have different easing curves and will reset properly even if the mouse leaves before the mouse enter animation is complete.

```css
.target {
  padding: 10px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  width: 50%;
  
  /* the transition does all the work */
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}

.target:hover {
  /* use a transform for easier position movement */
  transform: translateX(200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="target">Hover over me</div>
```

Comment: It seems to be following the cursor, is that really what he OP wants?

Comment: It isn't following the cursor. The OP wants it to slide to the side on mouseover and then slide back in to place when they leave.

Comment: Try moving the cursor in the first half of the screen on the same line, its following the cursor there.

Comment: @11thdimension it's not following the cursor, that's the element moving out of the way which then immediately triggers a mouse leave.

Comment: When the cursor moves horizontally in the first half of the screen, net effect is that the `#root` follows the cursor. That seems annoying to me. Well its better than the JS one which seems to move even after the cursor has been removed. I think that the cursor movement event should not be caught by the thing that's moving. It should be the parent. or anything else that isn't moving.

Comment: This is just an example to show how CSS transitions can do the same job, i could have made it move up and down or scale or rotate, this just seemed vaguely like what the OP wanted but they never explained what they actually needed.

Comment: Soviut, yes, this is what I am looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because `left` and `right` positioning don't always override each other. You need to remove one before the other one can be observed:

```
$('#root').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css( "left", "" );
    $(this).animate({
        'right': '200'
    });
});
$('#root').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css( "right", "" );
    $(this).animate({
        'left': '200'
    });
});
```

Or if you simply want to return to its original position, you could just return the `right` value back to 0:

```
$('#root').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'right': '200'
    });
});
$('#root').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'right': '0'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `'left': '200'` use `'right': '0'`.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My Practice Page</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="master.js"></script>

<style>
#root {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
</style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="root">

        </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#root').mouseenter(function() {
   $('#root').animate({
            'right': '200'
        });
    });
    $('#root').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#root').animate({
            'right': '0'
        });
    });
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

This works because you are animating two different things.

Comment: That is what I was looking for! Too simple. Thank you!